# How can I make dropdown appear as though it is coming out from behind button?

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu with everything working except for the stack order. I would like it to appear as though it is coming out from behind the button but it continues to appear in front of the button even though I have used z-index. Here is the code:

```css
.subnav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.05s;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  padding: inherit;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  min-width: 110px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0.05s linear 0.3s, z-index 0.3s linear 0.01s, transform 0.14s;
}

.subnav a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.black-text {
  color: black;
}

.subnav-element {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-element subnav-wrapper"><a class="black-text" href="#">ABOUT</a>
          <div class="subnav">
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">WHO WE ARE</a>
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PARTNERS</a>
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because of  `transform: translateY(-100%);` remove transform property from `.subnav` class. see updated snippet below:

```css
.subnav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.05s;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  padding: inherit;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  min-width: 110px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0.05s linear 0.3s, z-index 0.3s linear 0.01s, transform 0.14s;
}

.subnav a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.black-text {
  color: black;
}

.subnav-element {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-element subnav-wrapper"><a class="black-text" href="#">ABOUT</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <a class="subnav-element" href="#">WHO WE ARE</a>
    <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
    <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PARTNERS</a>
    <a class="subnav-element" href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your **css** (`transform: translateY` property). Check the below code it will helps you.

```css
.subnav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.05s;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  padding: inherit;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;  
  min-width: 110px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0.05s linear 0.3s, z-index 0.3s linear 0.01s, transform 0.14s;
}

.subnav a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  
 
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.black-text {
  color: black;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
}

.subnav-element {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-element subnav-wrapper">
  <a class="black-text" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <div class="subnav">
        <a class="subnav-element" href="#">WHO WE ARE</a>
        <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
        <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PARTNERS</a>
        <a class="subnav-element" href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this works for you, move transition to subnav wrapper instead of subnav, in this case, it won't seem like coming on top of about button. But generally, it should remain hidden if it is behind the About button.

```css
.subnav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0.05s linear 0.3s, z-index 0.3s linear 0.01s, transform 0.14s;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0, 0, 0.55s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.subnav-wrapper:hover .subnav a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  padding: inherit;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
  min-width: 110px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.subnav a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.black-text {
  color: black;
}

.subnav-element {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="nav-element subnav-wrapper">
<a class="black-text" href="#">ABOUT</a>
          <div class="subnav">
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">WHO WE ARE</a>
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">PARTNERS</a>
            <a class="subnav-element" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```